# Spring boot Graphql endpoint gives 404 not found

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am trying to build a graphql server using spring boot.

When I start my server and try to access the **localhost:8080/graphql** endpoint, it keeps throwing the 404 not found error.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

I have paced my schema files in the resources -> graphql folder. This is contents of one of the schema files

```gql
type Query {
    bankAccount(id: ID): BankAccount
}
```

Here's my pom file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphqlTut</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>graphqlTut</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java-kickstart/playground-spring-boot-starter &ndash;&gt;
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>playground-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And this is my QueryResolver class

```java
@Component
public class BankAccountResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

  public BankAccount bankAccount(UUID id){
      return BankAccount.builder().id(id).currency(Currency.USD).name("XYZ").build();
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your application configuration look like?

Comment: application.yml is empty

Comment: Where is the `/graphql` endpoint supposed to come from then if it's not your context path?

Comment: pls help me understand, I am doing this for the first time. Where do I need to add the endpoint information?

Comment: See the docs ~ https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot#enable-graphql-servlet

Comment: Check the application startup logs to see if the schema is getting auto detected.